# "Go to a section" is not working in java email

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

I am sending an html email from java, email goes fine and all elements are displaying properly but "go to" is not working.

```
<html><body>
<a href='#1'>sub1</a> 
<h1 id='1'>description1</h1>
</body></html>
```

The above code is working fine in a browser, that is on clicking sub1, it takes me to description1 but the same is not working in outlook email.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Pls include more code

Comment: What if you make the id start with a letter, e.g. `v1`?

Comment: So why should this be related to java? Rule of thumb: no java code in question, no relation...

Comment: @AndyTurner, I have tried adding a letter but no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try name attribute instead of id:

```
<html><body>
<a href='#foo1'>sub1</a> 
<a name="foo1"></a><h1 id='1'>description1</h1>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you please help me understand why it worked, I mean what is the difference between name and id in this context.  I have also tried adding name in h1 tag, it didnt worked where as with anchor it worked. Why is it so?

Comment: I can't explain why this works. I just have had the same issue and found this somewhere. Each email client (mobile or desktop) treats anchor links differently and not always in the same way as a browser does. For example a `Back to Top Anchors: <a href="#top">Back to top</a>` works with outlook but not in gmail whereas name anchors like the example above work in both.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it has to do more with the particular email client you're using than with the code that creates the email. Many email clients do not support "jump links" (anchor links), so no matter what you do, these links won't work. Try your email on other email clients (Outlook Web, Gmail, iOS Mail App, Yahoo) to see whether the anchor link works.